# PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, command-line

I have written (with Eclipse) a small program which uses JPA. Now I want to manualy compile and run this program using command line. I have also  placed all source files in a separate directory (not within Eclipse's work space). The directory looks like:

```
directory
  |- src
  |   |- javax
  |   |   |- persistence
  |   |        |- <...>
  |   |- main
  |   |- META-INF
  |   |   |- javax
  |   |   |    |- persistence
  |   |   |- persistence.xml
  |   |
  |   |- <..>
  |- run.bat
```

Note: I purposely have 2 javax directories with all the class files in them.

run.bat contains lines:

```
javac -cp ./src ./src/main/Main.java
java -cp ./src main.Main
```

As far as I understand I am getting errors not because of the issue with the META-INF/persistence.xml file (not like many other people on stackoverflow). I am saying so because I have writen following lines in my Main:

```
<...>
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new ClassLoader() {
            @Override
            public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("resource requested=" + name);
                if (name.equals("META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider")) {
        <--- MARK --->     return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(new File("src/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.class")
                            .toURI().toURL()));
                } else if (name.equals("META-INF/persistence.xml")) {
                    return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(new File("src/META-INF/persistence.xml")
                            .toURI().toURL()));
                }
                return super.getResources(name);
            }
        });
emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("uzduotis");
<...>
```

So when I launch run.bat the program prints:

`resource name=name=META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

(it never gets to the part where program asks for "META-INF/persistence.xml" resource)

then it breaks and gives me an error:

[image]

If I change MARKED statement to

```
return super.getResources("src/" + name);
```

then the error says only:

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Peristence.xml:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Program prety simple: no hibernate, just a few classes which retrieve some info from REST service and work with it, mainly using javax and w3c external libraries. Photo of the project explorer to depict its simplicity.

[image]

**EDIT 2. SOLUTION**

I found a way to make it work although I am not entirely sure about the causes. So **if anyone could answer why the following changes solved the issue I would gladly mark it as an answer**

I added eclipselink and mysql-connector-java jars to the *src* directory. eclipselink.jar fixed the issue and mysql-connector-java.jar was needed because I got other error (I am working with database afterall). Finally I changed line in the run.bat file from

```
java -cp ./src main.Main
```

to

```
java -cp ./src;./src/eclipselink.jar;./src/mysql-connector-java.jar; main.Main
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1285436/1506009

Comment: Which part on that post do think can solve my problem?

Comment: Well it seems that you didn't specify the persistence provider in your persistence.xml file. So i would try to specify it as in the linked answer.

Simply try to add `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` inside `<persistence unit name="uzduotis">` element. Remember that you need to have dependencies resolved for HibernatePersistence.

Comment: Oh. I probably should specify my program. Will edit question info shortly. Just so you know I am not using hibernate and as I said on the question I don't think that this issie with the persistence.xml file because this resource is never requested. But if you think that is not the case please prove me wrong

Comment: Ok. I'll look into this once again, right after you edit information. ;)

Comment: Instead of screenshotting your code, copy-paste it as text into a code block, please

Comment: Its easier to printscreen than align all the rows so they would look good sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your application is a standard Java SE application. JPA does not work automatically, as standard Java SE environment does not contain any implementation of JPA interfaces. It seems that Eclipse adds eclipselink to the classpath under the cover, therefore your program works when you run it from within Eclipse. But when you run your program from command line, you need to add `eclipselink`, which is a library that contains functionality for JPA interfaces.

You may try to generate Ant build file from eclipse project, and you would see if it adds eclipselink into the classpath in build.xml file. Or even better, I recommend to turn your project into project with Maven build - you would be able to build and run your project using Maven command in the same way as Eclipse would execute it (as Eclipse uses Maven under the cover for Maven-based projects).

**Edit - explanation of the role of eclipselink in JPA**

Packages starting `javax.persistence` are mostly interfaces, annotations, they have very few classes in fact. They only define how your application communicates with underlying persistence mechanism in standard way. On the other hand, you need to include also library with implementations (classes) for the standard JPA interfaces. `javax.persistence.Persistence` is just a facade, which delegates all the hard work onto an implementation, which might be Eclipselink, Hibernate, or something else.

The relationship between `javax.persistence` and EclipseLink is similar to relationship between interfaces and classes. You may use interfaces in your code, but your application will work only if you supply interfaces with real classes at some point.

It is also possible to use Eclipselink directly and skip whole `javax.persistence` layer, similarly as it is possible to work with real classes directly without through interfaces. But then you need learn internal API of Eclipselink and it is not possible to change Eclipselink library for alternatives like Hibernate. Nor will you be able to reuse the knowledge of Eclipselink-specific API to a project, which uses Hibernate. Reusability of a standard API is the most important case for standardized `javax.persistence` interfaces.

Maybe you wonder, how the persistence API knows where it should delegate the required functionality. There are multiple hooks, how it can find out. It is possible to include path to the main implementation class in `persistence.xml` using `provider` element. Or, it simply works if you include Eclipselink into the classpath, as Eclipselink library contains special text file at standardized path, which contains required information. This special file is inside Eclipselink JAR at path `META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` - does it ring the bell?

Comment: Can you tell more about what exactly eclipselink does in this scenario and why javax dont have the so needed implmenetations?

Comment: I added more explanation into the answer.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322827/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named-x/22224589#22224589. It contains additional technical details.